# Color coded Calendar is not working as expected

Tags: 2010, site-collection, spservices, sharepoint-calendar

I have used the below code to color code for my calendar in my `SP 2010 site's`home.aspx`page within a`Content Editor Web Part`.
But somehow, no color been added when I create a new item in the calendar list.

I have referred [here](http://www.miq.in/Style%20Library/Webpart/TrainingCalendarDispForm.txt) for the below code.

What I am doing wrong or missing here?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('WaitForCalendarToLoad');
  function WaitForCalendarToLoad() {
      if (SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4a) {
        var pwold$4a = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4a;
        SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4a = function () {
            pwold$4a();
            ColourCalendar();
        }
     }
     if (SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4b) {
        var pwold$4b = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4b;
        SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4b = function () {
            pwold$4b();
            ColourCalendar();
        } }}
    function ColourCalendar() { 
    $("a[href*='?ID']").each(
       function (i) {
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        var webhref = href.substring(0,href.indexOf('/Lists'));
        var IDVal = href.substring(href.indexOf('ID=')+3);
        IDVal=getListDataInfoProgram(IDVal);
        var FinalUrl = webhref + "/Pages/ProgramDetails.aspx?pid=" + 
         IDVal; 
        $(this).attr("href", FinalUrl);
        $(this).attr("onclick", '');
       });          }
    function getListDataInfoProgram(varID) 
    {    try     {
     var ProgramID;
      var CamlQuery = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value 
        Type='Counter'>"+ varID +"</Value></Eq></Where></Query>"; 
        var CamlViewFields = "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef 
         Name='Program' /></ViewFields>"; 
         $().SPServices({
          operation: "GetListItems",
          async: false,
          listName: "Training Calendar",
          CAMLViewFields: CamlViewFields,
          CAMLQuery: CamlQuery,
          completefunc: function (xData, Status) 
          {
          $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").each(function() 
          {                   
             ProgramID = ($(this).attr("ows_Program")).split(";");
        });              }              });                                          
      } catch(e)    { }     return ProgramID[0];         
      }  </script>
```

Comment: Do previously created items have color? If you refresh the calendar, does the new item show color?